# What are the consequences of leaving a postdoc position without notice?

Tags: postdocs, legal-issues

What is the worst thing would happen to a person who leaves their postdoc position without any prior notice and leaves the country?

Comment: Worst for whom? Also, what is bad depends on a lot of other circumstances.

Comment: it will also depend on the country you are trying to leave (and its labor laws) and if you are planning to go back there in the forseeable future.

Comment: What is the worst that could happen: Your current/former employer could find you and take some inspiration from horror movies and takes revenge accordingly on you, your family and loved ones. It is highly unlikely, but you asked the worst case scenario...

Comment: Why was it worse to not give an appropriate notice?

Comment: I would like to take this chance to clarify that this is merely a question, not an implication. I neither did nor am I planning on doing such thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that personal consequences for OP are being asked.

If the postdoc position is ruled by a working contract, you can be sued for failing to delivery what you promised. It is a workplace issue, more than an academic issue.

You may be put on trial and judged in-absentia, you may be prevented from entering again that country and/or you may have nasty surprise while travelling.

It depends a lot on which country you are citizen, which country you are working, what kind of agreement rules the postdoc.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the legal problems mentioned by @EarlGrey your reputation could also suffer. If you need a letter of recommendation, then you have a problem. More generally, a lot of (sub-(sub-))disciplines are like small gossipy villages. You pull a stunt like that, then that will be known. Who wants to employ someone who might just leave without warning?